# Can I use constant values in key value pair object in javascript

Tags: javascript, constants

I would like to define a set of constants, which I then use the values of in another javascript object.  I have the below example.

This however doesn't seem to work when I am trying to use 0 as a key for example.

Is there a way to get this to work?

```
export const PENDING_ACTIVATION = 0;
export const ACTIVE = 1;
export const SUSPENDED = 2;

export const userStatus = {
    PENDING_ACTIVATION : 'Pending Activation',
    ACTIVE : 'Active',
    SUSPENDED : 'Inactive'
};
```

Comment: You might need to use the object initialization syntanx differently by wrapping those keys in brackets: `{ [ACTIVE]: 'Active }` for example. The value of the variable is copied into the object, without the `const` qualifier. Really what you're attempting to do (if I understand correctly) is creating a key where `userStatus[1] = 'Active'`, not `userStatus.ACTIVE = 'Active'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `[key]` notation to create keys at the time of object initialization.

```js
const PENDING_ACTIVATION = 0;
const ACTIVE = 1;
const SUSPENDED = 2;

const userStatus = {
    [PENDING_ACTIVATION] : 'Pending Activation',
    [ACTIVE]: 'Active',
    [SUSPENDED] : 'Inactive'
};
console.log(userStatus);
```

Comment: fantastic just what I wanted.

Comment: just a note, I was curious what is this syntax, turns out it's called "computed property names", see more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names